# Text Positioning based on PHP-generated dynamic image file(in a png format)

Tags: php

I have looked everywhere, but I can't find anything. 
 
I am trying to write a PHP script where I can have an image from a URL, and make it as a dynamic .PNG file. 
I then want to load it to the client/browser, and allow them to add text, and position it within the image's boundaries. Kind-of like a meme generator,

example:
https://imgflip.com/memegenerator

I plan on having the image be from $_GET if that's needed. I want to be able to save it with the text, and be able to also store the text positioning, etc.

Actually, if I can do this somehow in HTML it will work with what I need!

Comment: Maybe u should look into [HTML5 Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)?

Comment: How can I add an existing image onto a canvas?

Comment: There is some example in this [link](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/), also the link I provided before also shows how to use the canvas.

Comment: I am trying to add an existing .jpg, or .png image, not draw a predefined one :x

Comment: If you look at the website I linked, it also says how to load an image. You should start reading into it and Google before asking. But [here you have a link](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-canvas-meme-generator) that basically does this with HTML5 Canvas

Comment: The tutorial isn't seeming to work for me.

Comment: Okay, then look at this JSFiddle. 
There is an live example of it working too.
http://jsfiddle.net/yCX24/7/

Comment: With that JSFiddle, no text or images appear inside the canvas. I believe I've done everything right...

Comment: Are you sure you use a browser with support for HTML5 Canvas? 
This is how it looks like to me in the JSFiddle http://i.imgur.com/pkd5MiC.png

Comment: I am using Google Chrome, and hosting with XAMPP \ localhost. Would this be the right way of inputting the main .html file?<!doctype HTML>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
<canvas width=555 height=327></canvas>
<textarea id=top>One does not simply...</textarea>
<textarea id=bottom>Create a meme generator in HTML5 canvas</textarea>

<h1>Drag images into browser</h1>                                                     The fiddle displays ok

Comment: It looks right to me, Do you use HTTPS or HTTP?

Comment: Well since I am using localhost I don't know if I can even use HTTPS...

Comment: You can, you can always sign your own certificate.
But i guess you haven't done that. 
Have you tried to make a dummy output form the javascript file to check if it works and if the jquery works?

Comment: How would I do that? I don't really develop hard-coding HTML, I mostly use PHP.

Comment: if (window.jQuery) {  
    $("p").text("jQuery is loaded");  
} else {
    $("p").text("jQuery is not loaded"); 
}

Comment: Nothing happens when I do that.